# Apollo Client 3.x.x , Next JS, Sentry, Strapi

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, sentry

I am facing an issue , when i installed sentry to my next js project , suddenly CORS error occured in my apollo client 3.x.x , but the thing is it only give CORS error in useQuery not in useMutation.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:1337/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

its just weird. i have add option of integration in Sentry.init

```
integrations: [
    new BrowserTracing({
      tracingOrigins: ["http://localhost:1337/graphql"],
    }),
  ],
```

Help Needed !!

Comment: Try this: ["http://localhost:1337/graphql", "http://localhost:3000"]